# Php Array - Associando dados

Tags: php, array

Olá,
Gostaria de associar os dados de escolhidos em checkbox, com os de um input.
Tenho de um lado, uma lista de resultados, onde irei selecionar em um checkbox, e cada um receberá um novo valor escolhido pelo usuário.

Por exemplo:
Na tela aparece Carro1,carro2 e carro3.
O usuario escolhe carro1 e carro2, e define que o carro1 vai se chamar volks, e o carro2 vai se chamar ford.

então ao fazer o submit, terei o seguinte código para realizar essa operação:

```
No layout assim:
<input type="checkbox" name="carro[]" />
<input type="text" name="nome_definido_usuario[]" />



E no processamento:
    <?php
        $carro = $_POST['carro'];
        $nome_definido_usuario= $_POST['nome_definido_usuario'];

        $carro_implode = implode("",$carro);
        $nome_definido_usuario_implode = implode("",$nome_definido_usuario);
    ?>
```

Se eu fizer um echo em $carro_implode e $nome_definido_usuario_implode,
consigo visualizar o resultado de forma aleatória, como **Carro1,Carro2,Volks,Ford**. Mas como faço para que o resultado apareça de forma associada, como:

**Carro1: Volks

Carro2: Ford**

Algúem saberia?

Answer (score 1):

Pra fazer a associação, creio que fica melhor dessa maneira. Porque se algum checkbox não for marcado, não perde-se o índice:

```
<?php
if( $_POST ) {
    foreach( $_POST['carro'] as $key => $value ) {
        echo 'Carro '.$value.': ' . $_POST['nome_definido_usuario'][$value].'<br />';
    }
}
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="carro[]" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="nome_definido_usuario[1]" /> <br />

    <input type="checkbox" name="carro[]" value="2" />
    <input type="text" name="nome_definido_usuario[2]" /> <br />

    <input type="checkbox" name="carro[]" value="3" />
    <input type="text" name="nome_definido_usuario[3]" /> <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Comment: Quase.. O nome_definido_usuario, está chegando vazio... como se não houvesse nada informado no campo pelo usuário..

Comment: Você colocou o numero entre os colchetes? O número que está no value do carro[] tem que estar no colchete do nome_definido_usuario. Tipo isso: name="nome_definido_usuario[2]"

Comment: Não coloquei, porque estou utilizando dados vindos do BD, com while

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer essa associação usando a função [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-combine.php). Essa função vai retornar um novo array associativo a partir de dois arrays reccebido como parametro, onde o primeiro vai ser usados como chaves e o segundo como valor das chaves do primeiro. Emplementando fica:

```
<?php
//exemplo de dados submetidos pelo formulario
$_POST['carro'] = ['Carro 1', 'Carro 2'];
$_POST['nome_definido_usuario'] = ['Volks', 'Ford'];

$carros = $_POST['carro'];
$nomes = $_POST['nome_definido_usuario'];

//essa função vai criar um novo array associativo, usando 
//como chave o primeiro e o segundo como os valores de cada chave do primeiro
$carrosNomes = array_combine($carros , $nomes);

//mostrando o conteudo
var_dump($carrosNomes);
echo $carrosNomes['Carro 1'] . '<br>';
echo $carrosNomes['Carro 2'] . '<br>';

//ou de forma mais completa
foreach($carrosNomes as $carro => $nome){
    echo '<br>' . $carro . ': ' . $nome . '<br>';
}

?>
```

Isso gera como saida:

```
//saida do var_dump
array(2) { ["Carro 1"]=> string(5) "Volks" ["Carro 2"]=> string(4) "Ford" } 

//acessando chaves do aray $carrosNomes
Volks
Ford

//imprimindo chave e valor de cada elemento do array $carrosNomes
Carro 1: Volks

Carro 2: Ford
```

Sugestão: você poderia unir os input com name carro e nome_definido_usuario em um só. Algo como:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="carro[]" value="Volks">
<input type="checkbox" name="carro[]" value="Ford">
```

## Exemplo funcionando

Em um arquivo qualquer coloque o codigo abaixo:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['carro'])){

$carros = $_POST['carro'];
$nomes = $_POST['nome_definido_usuario'];

//essa função vai criar um novo array associativo, usando 
//como chave o primeiro e o segundo como os valores de cada chave do primeiro
$carrosNomes = array_combine($carros , $nomes);

//mostrando o conteudo
var_dump($carrosNomes);
echo $carrosNomes['Carro 1'] . '<br>';
echo $carrosNomes['Carro 2'] . '<br>';

//ou de forma mais completa
foreach($carrosNomes as $carro => $nome){
    echo '<br>' . $carro . ': ' . $nome . '<br>';
}

}
?>

<form method="post">
    <!--É necessario definir um valor para os inputs carro, pis o valor 
    padrão é on, o que pode causar sobrescrita-->
    <input type="checkbox" name="carro[]" value="Carro 1" />
<input type="text" name="nome_definido_usuario[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="carro[]" value="Carro 2" />
<input type="text" name="nome_definido_usuario[]" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Ao subter o formulario o mesmo arquivo será executado, e o trecho em php será interpretado, gerando a saida esperada.

## Solução para deixar de unir esses dois arrays

Basta usar um pouco de javascript para copiar (o value) o conteudo de um input para outro.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['carro'])){

$carros = $_POST['carro'];

//mostrando o conteudo
var_dump($carros);

//ou de forma mais completa
foreach($carros as $carro => $nome){
    echo '<br>' . $carro . ': ' . $nome . '<br>';
}

}
?>

<form method="post">
    <!--É necessario definir um valor para os inputs carro, pis o valor 
    padrão é on, o que pode causar sobrescrita-->
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="carro[]" value="" class="carros"/>
        <input type="text" name="nome_definido_usuario[]" class="nomes" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="carro[]" value="" class="carros"/>
        <input type="text" name="nome_definido_usuario[]" class="nomes"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
    var nomesDefinidos = document.querySelectorAll('.nomes');

    for (var i = 0; i < nomesDefinidos.length; i++) {
        nomesDefinidos[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
            this.parentElement.querySelector('.carros').value = this.value;
        });
    }
</script>
```

Basicamente foi dada uma classe para cada input (nome definido usuario), adicionado um evento de change (quando algo for escrito no input e o foco mudar), então o valor digitado no input será setado como valor do input checkbox.

Comment: coloquei assim:   $carros = $_POST['carro'];
$nomes = $_POST['nome_definido_usuario'];

$carrosNomes = array_combine($carros , $nomes);

foreach($carrosNomes as $carro => $nome){
    echo '<br>' . $carro . ': ' . $nome . '<br>';
}                                                                                                                          Mas não veio nenhum resultado.. nada aparece na tela.                                 E sobre a sugestão de unir, creio q não seria ideal, porque a idéia é permitir que o usuário modifique os nomes conforme escolha.

Comment: e com o var_dump($carrosNomes) apareceu bool(false)

Comment: @Neo Editei a pergunta para colocar um exemplo completo e funcionamento. Basta colocar em um arquivo .php e executar. Além disso coloquei um exemplo onde não é necessario usar dois arrays no servidor.

Comment: Preciso dos 2arrays como no exemplo.. mas coloquei aqui e continua sem obter nenhum resultado, nada aparece na tela.

Comment: @Neo Então você não esta executando corretamente, o codigo de "Exemplo Funcionando", nesse link do [phpfiddle](http://main.xfiddle.com/code_78149148.php). O arquivo `code_78149148.php` tem exatamente o conteudo colocado na resposta, com a saida esperada (após preencher, claro).

Comment: O link não abre

Comment: http://main.xfiddle.com/code_78149148.php ...pagina não encontrada.. =/

Comment: =(...alguém aí?

Comment: @Neo Acho que o link expirou. Tenta esse [novo](http://main.xfiddle.com/06969926/associando.php) (em até 48 horas).

Comment: Consegui testar somente hoje, já expirou. Mas dentro do contexto que montei considerando o exemplo inicial, não consigo reproduzir aqui. Deve ser algum detalhe minimo..

Answer (score 0):

```
    $carro = $_POST['carro'];
    $nome_definido_usuario= $_POST['nome_definido_usuario'];

    $arrayCarros = array($carro => $nome_definido_usuario);
```

Comment: Assim retorna apenas Array

Answer (score -1):

A maneira correta seria usar um array associativo ou criar um objeto

```
<?php
     $carro = $_POST['carro'];
     $nome_definido_usuario= $_POST['nome_definido_usuario'];

     $arrayCarros = array($carro => $nome_definido_usuario);
?>
```

Comment: Tentei fazer algo assim: $names2 = array('vw'=>'Volks','FD'=>'Ford','CH'=>'Chevro'); Mas não Ocorreu o desejado..